# Radio interference caused by Martian dust storm

Tags: story-identification, movie, plot-device

In comments below [this excellent answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46791/12102) to *Are there methods of lightning detection on Mars?* I lament not being able to remember where I'd read about radio noise in the receiver of a real-world Martian lander or rover being interpreted as electrical discharges in dust storms on the planet.

Now I'm afraid that I might be remembering something from a work of fiction.

**Question:** Was radio interference caused by Martian dust storms ever addressed in the 2000 film [Red Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Planet_(film))?

Science background: Dust particles can become charged in high velocity turbulence in a dry atmosphere due to collisions with each other or perhaps the surface.

Comment: Possibly The Martian? Have you read the book or seen the movie?

Comment: Real world searches. https://www.space.com/7102-lightning-detected-mars.html and lack of detection https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2010GL044368

Comment: @Moriarty I did see it, but don't recall much of it now; all I really remember is potatoes, poop, duct tape and a bit of orbital mechanics.

Comment: The dust storm is obviously a key plot device in The Martian, but I don't recall any mention of dust storms causing even radio interference let alone a radio blackout.

Comment: @lucasbachmann just fyi a short answer mentioning that Mars Express non‐detection would be considered a welcomed, interesting, informative and helpful answer to the linked Space SE question [Are there methods of lightning detection on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41097/12102)!

Comment: I've ransacked my book collection but I can find surprisingly few mentions of Martian dust storms causing communication problems, and none in which this is the main plot device. There are mentions of storms causing physical damage to antennae, but aside from this all I can find are throwaway comments e.g. in Ben Bova's novel *Mars* there is a comment: *the interference of the dust storm made the transmissions relayed from orbit sound faint, blurred with crackling static*.

Comment: @JohnRennie thank you for your speedy ransacking :-)

Comment: @uhoh ransacking is a somewhat haphazard business so I have probably missed some references, but I was surprised not to find anything. I started out expecting to find so many references that I'd be writing an essay as an answer.

Comment: I'm sure the Global Dust storm in Kim Stanley Robbinson's Red Mars causes some issues. But it's been too long since I read it to give a specific consequnce.

Comment: Opening this up to works *other than Red Planet makes this into an (off topic) list question

Comment: @Valorim will deleting the bit currently/temporarily in strikethrough reverse any close or down votes and comments to that effect?

Comment: @Valorum I don't see the problem, from my reading of the question the OP is looking for a specific work that they are remembering. That's the entire purpose of the [[tag:story-identification]] tag so of course it's opened up to more than just _Red PLanet_.

Comment: @Uhoh - I've retracted my close vote. The question is now answerable but as Carrot has pointed out, it's still not entirely clear if you're looking for a Story-ID or specifically asking about the film. I'm happy to let it stand though.

Comment: I think there is mention of radio interference from dust storms in James Blish's 'Welcome to Mars' - it's been a while since I read it though so I could be wrong

Comment: @Valorum thank you